# Distortion Risk Measure from Integral Form to Sum

Tags: integration, summation

I have a question about distortion risk measure. From what I understand the formula for distortion risk measure is:

$$\rho_g(X)= \int_{0}^{\infty}g(1-F_X(x))dx$$

$g(x)$ is a non-decreasing function with $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$. My question is how do you get to this form with x an ordered sample, that is $x_{i-1}$ < $x_i$ with $i=1,2,...,n$

$$\rho_g(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\bigg(g\bigg(\frac{n-i+1}{n}\bigg)-g\bigg(\frac{n-i}{n}\bigg)\bigg) x_i$$

Thank you

Comment: [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) guide to help you type maths.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first question so i dont know for to type maths.